# row is not adding to datagridview automatically

Tags: datagridview, row

In my datagridview, AllowUserToAddRow = true; When I start editing a cell, a new blank row is automatically added at the end and that is absolutely fine. But if I try to populate the whole row programmatically (e.g. say you click on a button that opens a child form, the child form when closed sends data to parent form that contains the datagridview and there you bind all data to the datagridview row) in that case a new blank row is not added automatically. If I start editing any cell data it results in the appearance of the desired blank row. What can be the problem?

### I think many of you have come across this problem earlier. Any one successfully addressed it? Please provide the soln.

Edit: Sample code attached

```
//Uses Linq-to-Entities
            IQueryable<Product> productQuery = from prod in sampleTaskContext.Product
                                               where prod.ProductId == enteredProdId
                                               select prod;

            List<Product> foundProd = productQuery.ToList();
            if (foundProd.Count <= 0)
            {
                ProductsForm prodForm = new ProductsForm();
                prodForm.ShowInTaskbar = false;
                if (prodForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    Product returnedProd = prodForm.fnFormatProductDataForOrder();                    
                    foundProd.Add(returnedProd);
                }
            }

            if (foundProd.Count > 0)
            {                
                int selectedRowIndex = this.dgvOrderEntryDetails.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
                dgvOrderEntryDetails.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells["colProdId"].Value = foundProd[0].ProductId;
                dgvOrderEntryDetails.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells["colDesc"].Value = foundProd[0].ItemDescription.ToString();
                dgvOrderEntryDetails.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells["colQty"].Value = 1;
                dgvOrderEntryDetails.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells["colListPrice"].Value = foundProd[0].SalesPrice;
                dgvOrderEntryDetails.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells["colDisc"].Value = 0;
                dgvOrderEntryDetails.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells["colPrice"].Value = foundProd[0].SalesPrice;
                dgvOrderEntryDetails.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells["colTotal"].Value = foundProd[0].SalesPrice;
```

### }

Edit:
[image]

Comment: Please provide some code demonstrating the problem - I've tried adding rows to the datasource of a datagridview and haven't seen any problem with the new row disappearing.

Comment: I hv attached the code. Please hv a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the following code snippet resolved my issue.

```
protected override void OnCellBeginEdit(DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnCellBeginEdit(e);
            if (e.RowIndex == this.NewRowIndex)
            {
                if (this[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value == null)
                    return;
                string value = this[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
                SendKeys.Send("{BackSpace}");
                SendKeys.Send(value);                
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going about this the wrong way - you should never need to directly add items to the DataGridView the way you are, and this is what is creating the behaviour you are seeing.

Trying instead setting foundProd as your DataGridView's DataSource (and making it a class level list) and then adding your new values to it.

Something like:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private List<Product> foundProd_;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        foundProd_ = new BindingList<FoundProd>();

        dataGridView1.DataSource = foundProd;
    }

    // This method is where you update the datasource from the linq query
    private void SomeMethod()
    {
        IQueryable<Product> productQuery = from prod in sampleTaskContext.Product
                                               where prod.ProductId == enteredProdId
                                               select prod;

        List<Product> foundProd = productQuery.ToList();

        if (foundProd.Count <= 0)
        {
            ProductsForm prodForm = new ProductsForm();
            prodForm.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            if (prodForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Product returnedProd = prodForm.fnFormatProductDataForOrder();                    
                foundProd_.Add(returnedProd);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I believe the bound list will automatically update - though you might want to use a BindingList instead as that certainly will.

Comment: Thnx David for ur guidance. But I need some more clarifications from you. I hv added an image for the complete idea. Here the first three columns are button columns. Rest columns are normal textbox columns. When user enters something in the Prod Id column and presses enter the whole row is populated with matching product from catalog with other details. So my doubt is can I specify DataSource for individual rows as you have explained?

Comment: @bikram You simply add the new row to the datasource - you don't specify a datasource for each row but for the entire grid, but the datasource is a list so you can add the new backing objects to the grid and they will appear.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (dgorderdtl.CurrentRow.Index + 1 == dgorderdtl.Rows.Count)
{
    this.dgorderdtl.CurrentRow.Cells[dgorderdtl.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex - 1].Value = oBrowseLookUp.SelectedIDVal;
    this.dgorderdtl.CurrentRow.Cells[dgorderdtl.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].Value = oBrowseLookUp.SelectedDescVal;
    dgorderdtl.Rows.Add();
    dgorderdtl_CellValueChanged(null, null);
    this.dgorderdtl.RefreshEdit();
}
```